# Laravel 5.4 validator unique on link table

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have three tables `user`, `game` and `game_user`

`game_user` is a link table where the primary key is the `user_id` and the `game_id`

What is the validation role for making sure that the new value added into the link table is unique?

The incoming payload is an array of game ids

Comment: You can use a composite key in your database unless you are trying to have soft deletes.

Comment: `$table->primary(['user_id', 'game_id']);`

Comment: You can set them as primary keys which would prevent duplicates. Then use a try catch block to throw error on duplicate insertion.